# Failed to compile when VS ResourceGroup project reference a .NET project that use Package SDK

Tags: visual-studio, azure, .net-core

With the old version of csproj you used to be able to add project reference to Azure Resource Group project. What this does is when the project is built, it will create a package.zip in the same folder as the resource group project artifacts. All the artifacts get bundle and upload to storage account which can then be use in ARM template for MSDeploy.

With the new csproj that uses project SDK it doesn't seems like that's possible anymore.

I has setup an example project here to demonstrate the error - https://github.com/minh-dang/ExampleProject

ResourceGroup1 project is referencing FunctionAppV3 project. When attempting to build you will see the below failures;

```
D:\dev\git\temp\ExampleProject\FunctionAppV3\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\bin\FunctionAppV3.dll
2>D:\dev\git\temp\ExampleProject\FunctionAppV3\FunctionAppV3.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project.
2>Done building project "FunctionAppV3.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>Done building project "ResourceGroup1.deployproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```